# Is there a combined overview of questions?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

Like a total (personalized) view of all questions of all currently active StackExchange Q&A sites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the new and improved [stackexchange.com filters*](https://stackexchange.com/filters/my-filters), you can create a filter for *all questions on all sites*, e.g. [this one](https://stackexchange.com/filters/10798/all-questions).

<sub>* "tag sets" are now called "filters"</sub>

Answer (score 2):

See Stack Exchange Tag Sets

- https://stackexchange.com/tagsets/popular